# Garbled code problem when converting wstring to string(About Minor Languages)

Tags: string, c++11, unicode, multilingual, wstring

ENV:Visual Studio 2015.
I used two methods to convert wstring to string：

```
//convert wstring to string 
std::string to_byte_string(const std::wstring& input)
{
    //std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>/*,wchar_t*/> converter;
    return converter.to_bytes(input);
}
```

```
std::string wstring2string(std::wstring wstr)
{
    std::string result;
    
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP/*CP_UTF8*/, 0, wstr.c_str(), wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    char* buffer = new char[len + 1];
    
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP/*CP_UTF8*/, 0, wstr.c_str(), wstr.size(), buffer, len, NULL, NULL);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    
    result.append(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;
    return result;
}
```

I used a string `chs` containing Chinese and `lao` containing Lao as the file path.Both of `to_byte_string()` results were unsatisfactory.The result of using `wstring2string()` to convert a path containing Chinese characters is correct, but the path containing Lao characters is incorrect.
result:[to_byte_string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzLaE.png)
[wstring2string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Jog.png)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    std::wstring lao = L"F:/Data/ປະເທດລາວ/2022-12-02.22O";
    std::wstring chs = L"F:/Data/中文/2022-12-02.22O";

    string chs_str = to_byte_string(chs);
    string lao_str = to_byte_string(lao);
    
    std::string str_chs = wstring2string(chs);
    std::string str_lao = wstring2string(lao);
    ...
}
```

How can we solve the problem of garbled characters when converting wstring type paths containing Lao language into string type? Or is there a method that can successfully convert paths containing Chinese or Lao language?